# Inicio de sesión en PHP autenticación

Tags: php, mysqli, login, autenticación

Estoy desarrollando un login con php y mysqli, implementando las cookies tambien...
Mi codigo es el siguiente solo es el archivo login, ya que es el que me esta dando guerra.

```
<?php

/*****************************************************************************/
session_start();

/*if (isset($_SESSION['admin_name'])) {
    switch ($rol) {
        case 1:
            header('location: adminPag/');
            $_SESSION['admin_name_admin'] = $nameU;
            break;
        case 2:
            header('location: profPag/');
            $_SESSION['admin_name_profe'] = $nameU;
            break;
        case 3:
            header('location: aluPag/');
            $_SESSION['admin_name_alu'] = $nameU;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}*/
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    include("config.php");
    $conect = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password, $database) or die("No se pudo establecer conexion");
    if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $nameU = $_POST['user'];
        $passU = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cuentas WHERE correo='" . $nameU . "' AND contraseña='" . $passU . "';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conect, $query) or die("Hubo un error durante la consulta");
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($user) {
            $rol = $user[4];
            switch ($rol) {
                case 1:
                    if (!empty($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                        setcookie("login_User_admin", $nameU, time() + 84600);
                        setcookie("login_User_password_admin", $passU, time() + 84600);
                        $_SESSION['admin_name_admin'] = $nameU;
                    } else {
                        if (isset($_COOKIE['login_User_admin'])) {
                            setcookie("login_User_admin", "");
                            $_SESSION['admin_name_admin'] = $nameU;
                        }
                        if (isset($_COOKIE['login_User_password_admin'])) {
                            setcookie("login_User_password_admin", "");
                            $_SESSION['admin_name_admin'] = $nameU;
                        }
                    }
                    header('location: adminPag/');
                    $_SESSION['admin_name_admin'] = $nameU;
                    break;
                    /***********************************************************************************************************************/
                case 2:
                    if (!empty($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                        setcookie("login_User_profe", $nameU, time() + 84600);
                        setcookie("login_User_password_profe", $passU, time() + 84600);
                        $_SESSION['admin_name_profe'] = $nameU;
                    } else {
                        if (isset($_COOKIE['login_User_profe'])) {
                            setcookie("login_User_profe", "");
                            $_SESSION['admin_name_profe'] = $nameU;
                        }
                        if (isset($_COOKIE['login_User_password_profe'])) {
                            setcookie("login_User_password_profe", "");
                            $_SESSION['admin_name_profe'] = $nameU;
                        }
                    }
                    header('location: profPag/');
                    $_SESSION['admin_name_profe'] = $nameU;
                    break;
                    /***********************************************************************************************************************/
                case 3:
                    if (!empty($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                        setcookie("login_User_alu", $nameU, time() + 84600);
                        setcookie("login_User_password_alu", $passU, time() + 84600);
                        $_SESSION['admin_name_alu'] = $nameU;
                    } else {
                        if (isset($_COOKIE['login_User_alu'])) {
                            setcookie("login_User_alu", "");
                            $_SESSION['admin_name_alu'] = $nameU;
                        }
                        if (isset($_COOKIE['login_User_password_alu'])) {
                            setcookie("login_User_password_alu", "");
                            $_SESSION['admin_name_alu'] = $nameU;
                        }
                    }
                    header('location: aluPag/');
                    $_SESSION['admin_name_alu'] = $nameU;
                    break;
                    /***********************************************************************************************************************/
                default:
                    echo "Valor incorrecto";
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <p class="text-center dont-do text-secondary">
                <h2>Datos incorrectos</h2>
            </p>
            <?php
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($conect);
        }
    }
}
//mysqli_free_result($result);
//mysqli_close($conect);
?>
```

Ese es mi codigo, se trata de un incio de sesion con roles de usuario (admin, alumno, profesor).
Mi problema: Mi problema es que al momento de ingresar un correo con una contraseña incorrecta me muestra el mensaje "dato incorrecto", pero la segunda vez que intento ingresar algo, el boton de ingresar se me bloquea completamente y en el navegador me aparece lo siguiente "[En desuso] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.".
Ojala pudieran orientarme

```
   <?php
require_once("../config.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("location: ../login.php");
}
if ($_SESSION['tipo'] != 1) {
    header("location: ../login.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>administrador</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El problema que describes ocurre en el cliente. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código que usas en el cliente.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo agregue

Comment: Explica cómo tienes organizados tus archivos, no logro encontrar el hilo de tu código.

Comment: Tengo mi carpeta proyecto esta tiene el login.php. Dentro de la misma carpeta proyecto tengo tres carpetas (Nombre de ellas: adminPag , aluPag , profPag) , una para admin, otra para profe y la ultima para alumno, cada una de estas tres tiene su index.php.